# Scatterplot with best fit curve selected by AIC

Tags: r, plot, curve, loess

I am trying to write a function that does the following:
1. Produces and x,y scatterplot
2. Add a loess curve
3. Add a curve based on an AIC model fitting procedure where the best fit model could be linear, quadratic, or cubic. I want only a single line drawn for this step (i.e., the best fit, not all 3 possibilities).

I can do steps 1 and 2, but can't make #3 work. Where am I going wrong? Sample data below, but I will be running this function on various data sets, some of which will vary in length and NAs.

```
maindata = structure(c(1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 
1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 
1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 
1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 
1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, -1.54, 
1.5, 3.26, -2.79, 0.54, -0.51, -2.12, 1.83, -1.88, 0.47, -1.05, 
-2.16, -1.04, -1.77, -2.54, 1.67, -2.97, -2.58, NA, -0.08, 
2.05, 0.27, 2.18, 0.01, NA, -2.08, -0.42, -0.23, -1.58, -0.55, 
2.63, 0.38, 2.17, -3.09, 3.14, -3.01, -0.13, 2.38, 3.88, 1.14, 
2.54, 1.71, 2.86, -1.11, -1.98, -0.93, 1.03, 2.25, 1.18, -1.91, 
1, -0.09, 0.7, -1.35, -0.2, 1.35, 1.72, 0.72, -5.96, 2.95, -0.25, 
NA, 47, 40, NA, 20, 70, 80, 30, 33, 40, 71, 63, 25, 66, 41, 25, 
38, 18, 22, 60, 85, 30, 75, 25, 80, 65, 33, 85, 95, 45, 75, 19, 
75, 27, 13, 14, 15, 99, 22, 10, NA, 20, 35, 17, 55, 35, 70, 47, 
24, 45, 38, 50, 90, 60, 50, 100, 42, 34, 55, 10, 15, 90, NA), .Dim = c(62L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("year", "x_values", "y_values")))


dd_plot = function(x, y, yaxis, xaxis) {
  subset.data = subset(maindata, x!="NA" & y!="NA"); 
  plot(subset.data$y~subset.data$x, pch = 20, ylab = yaxis, xlab=xaxis)
    lines(loess.smooth(subset.data$x, subset.data$y), col = "blue", lwd = 2, lty =2)
  fit = stepAIC(lm(subset.data$y~subset.data$x+I(subset.data$x^2)+I(subset.data$x^3)))
  lines(subset.data$x, predict(fit), col="red")
    legend("topleft", c("Lowess","Best Fit Polynomial"), lty = c(2,1), col=c("blue","red"), bty="n", xjust = -0.2)
}

dd_plot(y = y_values, x = x_values, yaxis = "Y_label", xaxis = "X_label")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't exactly describe which part "doesn't work" or in which way it doesn't match you expectations. You sample has a bunch of mismatching variable names which perhaps your real data doesn't, bit it's looking for `x` and `y` in maindata which actually has `x_values` and `y_values`. Then your call to `dd_plot` references variables `x_values` and `y_values` which don't exist.

But i'll assume you got past that are talking about the ball of string that's plotted rather than the simple curve for the best fit polynomial. The problem is that your data should be sorted by x-value when drawing lines. R just connects consecutive points. So i think you want

```
lines(subset.data$x[order(subset.data$x)], 
    predict(fit)[order(subset.data$x)], col="red")
```

instead of plotting the unsorted data. That returns

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different issues here.  Stylistically, you will typically want to use data frames instead of the "structure" that you generated.  The second issue is that you are mixing data inside the function with data outside.  This is not strictly wrong, but it will often make it more difficult to troubleshoot a problem.

Changing those fixed the issue:

```
maindata <-
  data.frame(year=c(1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 
               1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 
               1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 
               1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 
               1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
               2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013),
             x_values=c(-1.54, 1.5, 3.26, -2.79, 0.54, -0.51, -2.12, 1.83, -1.88, 0.47, -1.05, 
               -2.16, -1.04, -1.77, -2.54, 1.67, -2.97, -2.58, NA, -0.08, 
               2.05, 0.27, 2.18, 0.01, NA, -2.08, -0.42, -0.23, -1.58, -0.55, 
               2.63, 0.38, 2.17, -3.09, 3.14, -3.01, -0.13, 2.38, 3.88, 1.14, 
               2.54, 1.71, 2.86, -1.11, -1.98, -0.93, 1.03, 2.25, 1.18, -1.91, 
               1, -0.09, 0.7, -1.35, -0.2, 1.35, 1.72, 0.72, -5.96, 2.95, -0.25, 
               NA),
             y_values=c(47, 40, NA, 20, 70, 80, 30, 33, 40, 71, 63, 25, 66, 41, 25, 
               38, 18, 22, 60, 85, 30, 75, 25, 80, 65, 33, 85, 95, 45, 75, 19, 
               75, 27, 13, 14, 15, 99, 22, 10, NA, 20, 35, 17, 55, 35, 70, 47, 
               24, 45, 38, 50, 90, 60, 50, 100, 42, 34, 55, 10, 15, 90, NA))

dd_plot = function(x, y, ...) {
  subset.data = subset(data.frame(x, y), !is.na(x) & !is.na(y)); 
  plot(subset.data$y~subset.data$x,
       pch = 20, ...)
  lines(loess.smooth(subset.data$x, subset.data$y),
        col = "blue", lwd = 2, lty = 2)
  fit = stepAIC(lm(subset.data$y~subset.data$x+I(subset.data$x^2)+I(subset.data$x^3)))
  lines(subset.data$x, predict(fit), col="red")
  legend("topleft", c("Loess","Best Fit Polynomial"),
         lty = c(2,1), col=c("blue","red"), bty="n", xjust = -0.2)
}

dd_plot(y = maindata$y_values, x = maindata$x_values, ylab = "Y_label", xlab = "X_label")
```